# Save output from password generator to txt file with Tkinter app

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, pycharm

I am working on a standalone desktop app to generate a list of random passwords that are saved to a text file. I was able to create a working code in PyCharm that creates a text file there with a list of random passwords based on length of password and how many passwords to create. This works perfectly.

```
import random
import csv

password_len = int(input("What length would you like your password to be : "))
password_count = int(input("How many passwords would you like : "))
Chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
while 1:
    pwfile = open('passwords.txt','w')
    for x in range(0, password_count):
            password = ""
            for x in range(0, password_len):
                password_char = random.choice(Chars)
                password = password + password_char
            pwfile.write(password + '\n')
pwfile.close()
```

The issue I am running into is when I try to create the desktop app with Tkinter, I cannot seem to get the app to write to a text file. The code creates the pop up window and asks for the password length and how many. But after I enter those numbers and attempt to generate the file, the app just freezes. I think maybe the problem is I'm trying to write and save in the same function? Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

import random
import csv

root = Tk()
root.title('Password Server Generator')
root.geometry('400x600')

def PWgen():
    Chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    pw_count = int(passTextbox.get())
    pw_length = int(myTextbox.get())
    while 1:
        pwfile = open('passwords.txt', 'w')
        for x in range(0, pw_count):
            password = ""
            for x in range(0, pw_length):
                password_char = random.choice(Chars)
                password = password + password_char
            pwfile.write(password + '\n')

#Text asking for password length
password_len = Label(root, text="What length would you like your passwords to be : ")
password_len.pack()
#Box to enter password length
myTextbox = Entry(root, width=30)
myTextbox.pack()
#Text asking for how many passwords to generate
password_count = Label(root,text="How many passwords would you like to generate: ")
password_count.pack()
#Box to enter how many passwords to generate
passTextbox = Entry(root, width=30)
passTextbox.pack()
#Button to generate password list
myButton = Button(root, text="Generate Password", command=PWgen)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Ideally this would automatically create a password.txt file or give an option to save to desktop or automatically save to desktop. Any option is fine I just can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly. I tried adding a pwfile.close() to the end of the app loop but that still just crashes. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It freezes because you have an infinite loop (`while 1:`). Why do you have that loop?

Comment: @BryanOakley I added break at the end and it's still freezing. I couldn't figure out how to get the pwgen loop to work without a while loop but maybe that's unnecessary

Comment: don't add `break` but remove `while 1:` - you really don't need it. And your original version (without tkitner) also doesn't need `while 1:` - because it runs code forever. I'm wondering how you could run it.

Comment: @furas When I remove the while and just have a for loop, the output is blank

Comment: you must have something wrong with your system. Or maybe you forgot `close()` file. System doesn't have to send data directly to file but keep in buffer in memory - and it save when you close file. Or maybe you got some error. Did you run it in console to see errors? Code without `while 1` works correctly on my system . (of course if I use `close()`)

Comment: @furas oh, I missed this before but I did get an error: line 15, in PWgen
    pwfile = open('passwords.txt', 'w')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'passwords.txt'

Comment: maybe you forgot to close file and system thinks that someone still uses it and system doesn't allow to open it by script when you run it again.

Comment: or maybe run codes in folder in which you don't have permission to write files. You could use `print( os.getcwd() )` to see `Current Working Directory`